# Tyring to find max(count(*))

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a table like below

| Name | Season | count(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 2020 | 2 |
| Name2 | 2020 | 3 |
| Name3 | 2020 | 4**** |
| Name1 | 2021 | 5** |
| Name2 | 2021 | 3 |
| Name3 | 2021 | 1 |
| Name1 | 2022 | 3 |
| Name2 | 2022 | 4** |

And I want a table like

| Name | Season | count(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name3 | 2020 | 4 |
| Name1 | 2021 | 5 |
| Name2 | 2022 | 4 |

I've tried using

```
select max(count(*)) from ~~
```

, and I found that it's not gonna work.
Can you guys give me some adivice?

Comment: You can't nest aggregates. You need to do `COUNT(*)` in a subquery, the `MAX()` in the main query.

Comment: If you want to know the year with the max, you need to use [max-row-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1) using the count subquery as the table you're doing this to. A CTE or window functions will make this easier.